# Calling JSP's directly in AEM 6.2

Tags: aem

To call JSP's in AEM 6.2 I've been creating site pages then changing the resourceType to a JSP component. Without creating OSGi bundles, is it possible to call a JSP directly without having to go through the Page / Component reference method?

Answer (score 4):

In short No. That is against Sling principles. Quoting the documentation

> Sling Scripts cannot be called directly
>
> Within Sling, scripts cannot be called directly as this would break
>   the strict concept of a REST server; you would mix resources and
>   representations.
>
> If you call the representation (the script) directly you hide the
>   resource inside your script, so the framework (Sling) no longer knows
>   about it. Thus you lose certain features.

For more information, please refer [The Basics](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-2/develop/the-basics.html#Locating%20the%20script)